# Homology group of $S^2$ with a string

Tags: homology-cohomology

What is a homology group of $S^2$ with a string attached to it by both ends? (Name it $X$. Drawing in below)
I tried to decompose X as following, but I'm not sure if it's correct.
I'll appreciate any help.[image]

Comment: Sure, that is one possible decomposition. Now write down the Mayer-Vietoris sequence and milk it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wrote Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Here, can I say that i*:H1(A∩B)→H1(B) is a 0-map?

Comment: When I assumed i* a 0-map, I ended up H_q(X)=Z(q=0,1,2), {0}(otherwise)

Comment: Yes, $i_*$ is a zero map, since the nontrivial cycle in $A \cap B$ is contractible in $B$. Also, there is another way to do this problem by realizing that your space is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1$; this is because if you draw a line on the sphere connecting your two points, collapsing this line segment to a point is a homotopy equivalence, and the resulting space is $S^2 \vee S^1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's really helpful. I think I can proceed now.